# Append object from another layer to the new layer through form (drop-down list)

Tags: qgis, sql, list, ppygis

I'm trying to get to know is it possible to append object from another layer to the new layer through form (drop-down list)? Do I need to create an application? If yes please tell me what language would be the best for this kind of problem?

Example: I created new layer called Companies_objects. I have another layer (all_objects) with a lot of objects in town and some of theme belong to specific companies. I would like to append some Companies that interesting me (by it's names) from the drop-down list from all_objects layer when I'm editing new Companies layer. Is it possible?